# Exception with Java-MySQL connection

Tags: java, mysql, exception, connection, connector

I want to connect to DB with **Java** and **MySQL** but I´m having problems. I have a class in a package to connect with MySQL so I only have to create an object of this class in jsp file and this package is in Source Packages. I have added the MySQL Java connector to my Project Libraries too. But when I run the project and try to connect with DB I get an exception and I don't know what is the problem. Can you help me please?
Thanks!

The exception in NetBeans console:

*Grave: null

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
at DataBase.Model_DB.connectToDB(Model_DB.java:41)
at DataBase.Model_DB.executeSelect(Model_DB.java:57)
at org.apache.jsp._004_002dLogin.registrar_jsp._jspService(registrar_jsp.java:81)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)*
```

And the page with the lines that have the problem:

```
private Connection connectToDB(){
    try {
        //1-Cargar driver
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(direc,usuario,password);
        return cn;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Model_DB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Model_DB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }
}

//Funciones públicas
//Función sólo para sentencias select
public ResultSet executeSelect(String sql){
    //1-Conectamos
    Connection cn = this.connectToDB();
    try {
        //2-Realizar sentencia
        Statement st = cn.createStatement();
        return st.executeQuery(sql);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Model_DB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the required jar present in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing my sql connector in your classpath. You ca download it from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

Comment: I have the mysql-connector-java-5.1.25 in Libraries folder in my JavaWeb project. :|

Comment: Ok is that included in your classpath?

Comment: Do you mean this? public class Model_DB {
    private String direc,usuario,password,driver;

    public Model_DB() {
        this.direc="jdbc:mysql://localhost/java";
        this.usuario="root";
        this.password="";
        this.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    }

Comment: I mean to say that is your Libraries folder being utilized by the application?

Comment: Yes, I think, because in the project are Web Pages, Source Packages, Libraries and Configuration Files folders and in Libraries folder are JDK and Apache TomCat libraries too with mysql-connector.

Comment: Try redeploying, the stacktrace is for the application not getting mysql connector. Thats the issue.

Comment: So I have to create a new Libraries folder and add mysql-connector again or create a new project and paste everything in the new project or something like that?

Comment: You need to have a project which has a library folder and that folder should be in classpath. This applies for every project you create.

Comment: Ok, I think now I understand. I'm going to test it. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: If it solved your problem. Accepting the answer would help.

Comment: By clicking tick button, does it?

Comment: Yes. And a vote up will be appreciated.

Comment: Ok haha. Thank you all! Sorry :( Vote up I can't by level

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added the mysql driver jar in classpath. Download it from this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html)

Note : Please note that you can put the mysql-connector jar in tomcat/lib directory.so, all applications in your tomcat server can make use of it.

Comment: Yes, this is what is becoming me crazy, I have the mysql-connector-java-5.1.25 in Libraries folder in my project. Ok, I'll try with tomcat/lib! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL Driver jar file (MySQL calls these the Connector/J) is not available on your classpath. Here is the MySQL documentation on how to use that driver: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/index.html (chapters 3 and 4 are of most interest to you).

Comment: Ok, I'm going to see! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that your MySQL driver is referenced in you classpath! that should solve your problem

Comment: How can I do that, I mean, I have the mysql-connector in Libraries folder, so now how can I add to my classpath?

Comment: Add mysql-connector.jar to your classpath and also to your webserver's lib directory. Tomcat lib path is given as an example Tomcat\lib